# Регулярное выражение для диапазона чисел 1 - 31 включительно и учитывая стартовые нули

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь составить регулярное выражение для проверки выше указанного диапазона, так, что бы следующие комбинации 01, 07 или же просто 1, 7 были валидными. Пока есть такие наработки

(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]|[0-9])

но это выражение пропускает числа выше 31. Вопрос, как правильно составить регулярку?

Comment: Ограничьте начало и конец строки `^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-1]|[0-9])$` либо используйте негативный просмотр назад и вперед `(?<![0-9])...(?![0-9])` для установки границ чисел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

https://regex101.com/r/EypG2Q/1

> **01**
>
> **07**
>
> **12**
>
> **31**
>
> 32
>
> 42
>
> 51